# Android SQLite Emulator cannot run for database project

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi I am newbie for android coding, now I am learning about SQLite to do log in system...and I stuck with the problem that the emulator cannot even run this project. It show up Toast "welcome_error_message" from this code

```
Toast.makeText(this,getString(R.string.welcome_error_message),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

[Picture of Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXVZ6.png)

FYI I run ADB emulator 
Now, I don't know what is the exact problem and I try to update everything in SDK manager together with find the solution from existing question post but not found the same as my project.

Would it be possible to suggest the solution for me?

Please find my source below

[MainActivity.java]

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mChangePassword; TextView mUsername; private UserManager mManager; User mUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mManager = new UserManager(this);
        mUser = new User();

        mChangePassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_password);
        mUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.say_hi);

        Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (null == args) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.welcome_error_message),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            mUsername.setText(getString(R.string.say_hi) + " " +
                    args.getString(User.Column.USERNAME));

            mUser.setId(args.getInt(User.Column.ID));
            mUser.setUsername(args.getString(User.Column.USERNAME));
        }

        mChangePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialogPassword();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[User.java]

```
 public class User {
    public static final String TABLE = "user";

    public class Column {
        public static final String ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String USERNAME = "username";
        public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    }

    private int id; private String username; private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {}

    public int getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

    public String getUsername() {return username;}

    public void setUsername(String username) {this.username = username;}

    public String getPassword() {return password;}

    public void setPassword(String password) {this.password = password;}
}
```

[UserManager.java]

```
public class UserManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements UserManagerHelper {
    public static final String TAG = UserManager.class.getSimpleName();
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public UserManager(Context context) {
        super(context, UserManagerHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null, UserManagerHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE_USER = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s " +
                        "(%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)" ,
                User.TABLE,
                User.Column.ID,
                User.Column.USERNAME,
                User.Column.PASSWORD
        );

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);

        Log.i(TAG, CREATE_TABLE_USER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String DROP_USER = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + UserManagerHelper.DATABASE_VERSION;

        db.execSQL(DROP_USER);

        Log.i(TAG, DROP_USER);
        onCreate(mDatabase);
    }

    @Override
    public long registerUser(User user) {
        mDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(User.Column.USERNAME, user.getUsername());
        values.put(User.Column.PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

        long result = mDatabase.insert(User.TABLE, null, values);
        mDatabase.close();

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public User checkUserLogin(User user) {
        mDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(User.TABLE,null,User.Column.USERNAME + " = ? AND " +
                        User.Column.PASSWORD + " = ?",new String[]{user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()},null,null,null);

        User currentUser = new User();

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                currentUser.setId((int) cursor.getLong(0));
                currentUser.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
                currentUser.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
                mDatabase.close();
                return currentUser;
            }
        }   
        return null;
    }
}
```

[UserManagerHelper.interface]

```
public interface UserManagerHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ahoy_login";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public long registerUser(User user);
    public User checkUserLogin(User user);
}
```

[Logcat]

```
02-25 13:54:22.657 3297-3297/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10060: Read-only file system
02-25 13:54:22.657 3297-3297/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
02-25 13:54:22.658 3297-3297/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-25 13:54:22.702 3297-3297/com.gerpeace.databasetest I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.gerpeace.databasetest, real application class is null.
02-25 13:54:22.704 3297-3297/com.gerpeace.databasetest W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.gerpeace.databasetest/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.gerpeace.databasetest/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex) with checksum 0x3b5a494f in OatFile /data/data/com.gerpeace.databasetest/cache/slice-slice_4-classes.dex
02-25 13:54:22.903 3297-3297/com.gerpeace.databasetest W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-25 13:54:23.033 3297-3317/com.gerpeace.databasetest D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true

                                                                         [ 02-25 13:54:23.034  3297: 3297 D/         ]
                                                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xac67c160, tid 3297
02-25 13:54:23.037 3297-3297/com.gerpeace.databasetest D/Atlas: Validating map...

                                                                [ 02-25 13:54:23.075  3297: 3317 D/         ]
                                                                HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf20e1f0, tid 3317
02-25 13:54:23.077 3297-3317/com.gerpeace.databasetest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-25 13:54:23.102 3297-3317/com.gerpeace.databasetest D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-25 13:54:23.180 3297-3317/com.gerpeace.databasetest V/RenderScript: 0xa3f02c00 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
```

Comment: You should reduce your code to a smaller example. You can't seriously expect us to read that much of code. Please have a look at http://sscce.org/

Comment: So sorry for that long code...I just don't know where is the mistake. But, I already cut some code that I think it's not a problem. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: The problem is related to starting that activity; all the other code does not matter.

Comment: Could you advise for the way to fix it?